# Any EU country issuing long-term tourist visa?

Tags: visas, europe, residency

In Turkey, the main (and probably the only) requirement for obtaining one-year residence permit is to have enough money for staying in Turkey (about $6,000 in a Turkish bank).

Is there any other European country giving touristic residence permit (one year) based on financial support?

Comment: Can it be renewed?

Comment: I assume you're Turkish ? Theses things differ fir every nationality

Comment: By EU, do you really mean Schengen zone? In which case, not really, no. And with the humanitarian crises going on, coupled with what happened yesterday in Paris, any chance there was one, in my opinion, will go away very soon. I will wager travel to the continent and Europe in general, for citizens and tourists alike, will be getting much harder now.

Answer (score 4):

Even if I don't know all the rules and regulations of each and every EU country, I am pretty sure that you won't find any one-year residence permit that would be issued solely on the basis of a few thousands euros of wealth. The reason for that is that it would make it very easy to circumvent just about any other visa requirement and to immigrate illegally (hundreds of thousands of people are currently paying more than that to cross the border illegally and for many other things that could help them stay in the EU).

What you will find instead are the following:

- Six-month visit visas. While the regular Schengen short-stay visa can only cover stays up to 90 days, several EU countries (including [the UK](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview) and IIRC Sweden) allow you to stay a bit longer as a tourist.
- Working holiday visas. If you are eligible (it depends on age and citizenship), they allow one or two years of stay with minimal requirements.
- Semi-permanent residence status like the one mentioned by @phoog in France (you get one year at a time but it's renewable). In that case you must meet some financial requirements (higher than in Turkey but not that much higher, in France it's about €14000 for a year) but also credibly argue that you won't work during your stay. Implicitly, they are more intended for retirees and a few other special categories of people than for prime working age tourists.
- Investor's visas. If you are able to shell out a large amount of money on some local business venture, many countries offer special visas or even a quick path to citizenship. But we are talking about hundreds of thousands of euros and more, not just a few thousands.

Whether for three months, for six months or for longer, the main difficulty is that tourism visas are issued to people who will go back to their country of residence at the end of their stay. Having a stable situation in your country of origin is a requirement. For example, employees often need to show they have a job and are on paid leave.

But if you are ready to leave for a year or more, you are unlikely to have a job waiting for you and your ties to your country of residence are obviously weaker (otherwise you would need to be there more frequently) so unless you have significant wealth and business interests, you will look like a big risk to immigration officials.

Answer (score 0):

France has a similar program, the **Long stay visa for non professional purpose**:

> If granted, the visa issued is valid as a "Long Stay as Resident Card visa" for a maximum of one year.
>
> The visa in your passport will also be your permanent resident card for France for the whole first year.
>
> Should you then wish to stay more than a year in France, you will then have to contact the French local state authorities ("Préfecture") to apply for an extension of your stay by a permanent resident card ("Carte de Séjour") separate from your passport.

Source: http://www.consulfrance-washington.org/spip.php?article401

Comment: I don't think it's intended for tourism, but rather for retirees, elderly parents of legal residents, church ministers, etc. Legally, it's not restricted to a specific category of applicants but you have to explain why you want to stay in France. See also https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F302

Comment: Are non-EU holders of this visa subject to the 90/180 Schengen rule for countries other than France? (Leaving aside the relative difficulty of counting such days if there are no border controls.)

Comment: @AndrewLazarus all holders of the visa will be non EU, and yes, as with any Schengen residence permit, they will have to observe the 90/180 rule in other Schengen countries.

Comment: @phoog Sounds useful for retirement anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: The various EU countries offer long-term visa. The main focus of those visa is work or study, so [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) would be a better StackExchange forum.

For instance, a German Aufenthaltserlaubnis is generally provided for education, work, humanitarian reasons or family reunions, but [§7 AufenthG](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__7.html) states that it may be granted for other reasons (which are not enumerated).

Since EU countries are generally worried about illegal immigration, *just* demonstrating the funds for the intended duration of the stay isn't enough. (A substantial investment in the local economy may be a fast track to a residence permit or citizenship, but that wasn't the question here.)

Comment: I think you are confusing “short stay” with “tourism”. Anything longer than 3 months would certainly technically be a long-stay visa or temporary residence permit (as is the Turkish thing apparently) but something like that could still be issued for tourism/leisure visits (I vaguely recall that Sweden has a 6-month visitor visa similar to what the OP has in mind). Conversely, Schengen visas can be issued for many other things than tourism, even for work. So I am not sure that this comment really answers the question one way or the other.

Comment: @Relaxed, I didn't say that *all* short stay is tourism, I said that generally tourism uses the 90-day visa and anything beyond that is best asked on expats.

Comment: Maybe but I still feel your answer conflates many things in unhelpful ways. The Schengen rules assume nothing, they just cover stays under 90 days and let member countries deal with the rest. That's it, end of story. Also, it's more a comment than an answer. You don't say anything about what's possible or whether the requirements for such visas are different, you just discuss technicalities (whether it's Schengen and where to ask about it).